# How to change the default page

Tags: jquery, tabs

```
<div class="phonepager fcolrblk2c">
         Page
<a style="display: none;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage1','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage1">1</a><span id="pgrTop_lblPage1">1</span>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage2','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage2">2</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage3','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage3">3</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage4','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage4">4</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage5','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage5">5</a>&nbsp;
 | <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPageShowAll','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPageShowAll">See all on one page</a>&nbsp;
      </div>
```

I have this code for different pages to open. When we open the url the first page shows by default. How to make the "See all on one page" clicked by default instead of "1"?

Comment: We don't have this code.

Comment: Still not enough code...we need the `__doPostBack()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but are you looking for something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ckN2R/)**?

If so, then it seems like Page '1' link is hidden and a span is added for showing 1 as simple text. So I just moved the style from Page '1' link to 'See all on one page' and moved the span for showing '1' and changed it to 'See all on one page'.

You should probably achieve this using a javascript function.. Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ckN2R/1/) for javascript based solution on what you are trying to achieve.

**Code:**

```
$('.page_link').click ( function () {
    var selPage = this.id.replace('pgrTop_lnk', '');

    //reset all link    
    $('.sel_page_lbl').remove();
    $('.page_link').removeClass('hidden');

    $(this).after('<span id="pgrTop_lbl' + selPage + '" class="sel_page_lbl" >'+this.innerHTML+'</span>');

    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```